# Repeated function for every controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a function that populates an instance variable which is used to display site activity in a side bar.

As the site activity needs to be displayed on almost every controller action I am repeating the code in each controller and calling it from every action. So I have multiple copies of the same function. The activity function is independent of the controller and action.

Obviously this is wrong so my question is where should I place this function.

```
def activity
  @activity = Activity.all.limit(30)
end
```

**Application Layout**

```
<%= render partial: "shared/activity", collection: @activity %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could place this in the ApplicationController. The thing I would do is to use a before_action (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters). A sample would be:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_activities

  private

  def set_activities
     @activity = Activity.all.limit(30)
  end
end
```

You also don't need .all.limit you could do .limit right away.

Comment: And I could used an "except" on the callback to exclude the small number of controllers where I don't want it called I guess.

Comment: Exactly. Personally, I prefer using the positive list (so use *only*) in case you add new controllers in the future

Answer (score 0):

put the method in your application helper file and use direct instead of using as @activity object.

in application_helper.rb

```
def activity
  Activity.all.limit(30)
end
```

remove from controller

```
<%= render partial: "shared/activity" %>
```

In activity.html.erb

call `activity` method directly it will give list that you want.

Using above approach remove dependency from controller whenever you call render you don't need to pass `@activity` explicitly.

Comment: Using the helper method suggested can I pass it to a partial as a collection?
 <%= render partial: "activities/activity", collection: @activities %>